# Find pixel location on FAA Sectional using GDAL

Tags: c++, gdal

I am trying to convert a latitude and longitude position to a pixel location (x,y) in an GEOTIFF FAA Sectional Chart. For reference, here is some GDALInfo output for the Seattle sectional file I am working with.

```
    Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
    Files: d:\programming\gps\Seattle SEC 94.tif
    Size is 17869, 12333
    Coordinate System is:
    PROJCS["Lambert Conformal Conic",
        GEOGCS["NAD83",
            DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
                SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221010042,
                   AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],
            PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
            UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],
        PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],
        PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",46.66666666666666],
        PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",41.33333333333334],
        PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",46.75],
        PARAMETER["central_meridian",-121],
        PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
        PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
        UNIT["metre",1,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
    Origin = (-409375.329186913440000,261032.079643933710000)
    Pixel Size = (42.334884781508684,-42.335597515618694)
    Image Structure Metadata:
      COMPRESSION=LZW
     INTERLEAVE=BAND
    Corner Coordinates:
    Upper Left  ( -409375.329,  261032.080) (126d34'48.90"W, 48d58'12.69"N)
    Lower Left  ( -409375.329, -261092.845) (126d 8'14.67"W, 44d17' 3.85"N)
    Upper Right (  347106.727,  261032.080) (116d15'59.44"W, 49d 0'18.33"N)
    Lower Right (  347106.727, -261092.845) (116d38'32.78"W, 44d19' 0.07"N)
    Center      (  -31134.301,     -30.382) (121d24'26.75"W, 46d44'56.53"N)
```

I wrote the following exploratory code (C++) below. When I perform a transformation on the lat and long, the resulting pixel location is not what I expect.  For example, when trying to convert the center longitude and latitude position to an x, y pixel location.

```
   long = 121.407431 and  latitude = 46.749036  This is the center point from the GDALInfo output converted to decimal form.
```

I get:

```
    x = -6234845.2270864788 and y = 5392747.8923152313
```

Where as I expected:

```
    (Approx.)  x = 8935 and y = 6167
```

Clearly I have set up my transformation incorrectly, or additional translation and/or scaling is required. Here is my exploratory code in C++. This code was derived from similar questions on stack overflow, but the results are not what I expect. Appreciate any help you can offer.

```
    GDALAllRegister();

    GDALDataset* poDataset = (GDALDataset *)GDALOpen("D:\\programming\\gps\\Seattle SEC 94.tif", GA_ReadOnly);
    const char * szProjection = poDataset->GetProjectionRef();
    OGRSpatialReference dst(szProjection);
    OGRSpatialReference src;
    src.SetWellKnownGeogCS("WGS84");

    OGRErr error = dst.Validate();
    error = src.Validate();

    OGRCoordinateTransformation* pTransform = OGRCreateCoordinateTransformation(&src, &dst);

    // Center point of map in lattitude and longitude
    double lng = 121.407431;
    double lat = 46.749036;

    double x = lng;
    double y = lat;

    pTransform->Transform(1, &x, &y);
```

Value of x and x not what I expected.
Actual:    x = -6234845.2270864788 and y = 5392747.8923152313
Expected: (Approx.)  x = 8935 and y = 6167

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A last step is needed, you have to convert from image geotransform to pixel:

```
double georef[6];
poDataset->GetGeoTransform(georef);

int pixelX = int((x - georef[0]) / georef[1]);
int pixelY = int((y - georef[3]) / georef[5]);
```

Comment: Thanks Sga!  That fixed things nicely. I did have to make one other minor change.  I had to express my longitude as a negative number (-121.407431).  Not sure why yet, but everything is working now. I am happy. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Notice that GDAL outputs in a format which includes the hemisphere (`W` in this case), `121d24'26.75"W`. If you convert that to decimal format, coordinates on the western hemisphere are negative (otherwise you'll literally end up in China).